# ElasticSearch nested _count query gets "request does not support [filter]"

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query that works fine when I run it using `_search`, but it fails when using `_count`.  Can someone tell me why?  I'd rather not have to run the complete query just to get a count.

This is the query.

```
{
  "filter": {
    "nested": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "user_id": 5
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }, 
      "path": "participants"
    }
  }
}
```

This is the failure:

```
{
    "count": 0,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 0,
        "failed": 5,
        "failures": [
            {
                "index": "messages_20150428_000025",
                "shard": 0,
                "reason": "BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[messages_20150428_000025][0] ]; nested: QueryParsingException[[messages_20150428_000025] request does not support [filter]]; "
            },
            {
                "index": "messages_20150428_000025",
                "shard": 1,
                "reason": "BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[messages_20150428_000025][1] ]; nested: QueryParsingException[[messages_20150428_000025] request does not support [filter]]; "
            },
            {
                "index": "messages_20150428_000025",
                "shard": 2,
                "reason": "BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[messages_20150428_000025][2] ]; nested: QueryParsingException[[messages_20150428_000025] request does not support [filter]]; "
            },
            {
                "index": "messages_20150428_000025",
                "shard": 3,
                "reason": "BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[messages_20150428_000025][3] ]; nested: QueryParsingException[[messages_20150428_000025] request does not support [filter]]; "
            },
            {
                "index": "messages_20150428_000025",
                "shard": 4,
                "reason": "BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[messages_20150428_000025][4] ]; nested: QueryParsingException[[messages_20150428_000025] request does not support [filter]]; "
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Given this the mapping for this nested field:

```
"participants": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
        "archived": {
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "has_unread": {
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "pk": {
            "type": "long"
        },
        "user_id": {
            "type": "long"
        }
    }
},
```

and these data (for this nested field only):

```
"participants": [
    {
        "archived": false,
        "user_id": 5,
        "name": "Person A",
        "has_unread": false,
        "pk": 1
    },
    {
        "archived": false,
        "user_id": 7,
        "name": "Person B",
        "has_unread": false,
        "pk": 2
    }
],
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html) ***count*** can accept only query hence you would need to rewrite it as

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "nested": {
               "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {
                           "term": {
                              "user_id": 5
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               "path": "participants"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While that does answer the question, it doesn't help me with how to get what I want, so, I'll upvote it, but here's the solution to my question:

```
/_search?search_type=count
```

simple as that.